# Reverse row order in a data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I got the following data frame:

```
A   B
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

And I want to reverse row order in all columns (turn it "upside down"):

```
A   B
5   6
3   4
1   2
```

I used the following code

```
sort(df[ , 1:2], decreasing = TRUE)
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : undefined columns selected
```

when I specify only one column it works but I need both the columns to be sorted at once.

Comment: Try `df[nrow(df):1,]`

Comment: If you want it upsidedown, then that's not really sorting at all. try `df[nrow(df):1,]`

Comment: Do you think I should edit the question to make it more clear? @MrFlick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `rev` to reverse the row names

```
df[rev(rownames(df)),]
#   A B
# 3 5 6
# 2 3 4
# 1 1 2
```

If you want to correct the new reversed row names, you could write a little function

```
flip <- function(data) {
    new <- data[rev(rownames(data)), ]
    rownames(new) <- NULL
    new
}
flip(df)
#   A B
# 1 5 6
# 2 3 4
# 3 1 2
```